# Different flash Tab-Focus behavior in Firefox and Internet Explorer

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, focus, tabs, focusmanager

In a minigame that is part of a larger flash game we show a number of editable textfields, about 10 rows with two textfields per row. Every row of two textfields is encapsulated in a class, and objects of that type are placed under each other so that it looks like some sort of table.

Now on Firefox the tab behavior is fine, after manually focusing the first textfield the tab key moves the focus first to the right, then to the next row, again to the right, etc...

In Internet Explorer 8 (using flash player version 10) the focus moves directly to the next row, ignoring the field to the right of the current one.

This is one of the first times I've noticed a real difference between the flash player in Firefox and the one in Internet Explorer. Does anyone know why they are reacting differently and what to do about it?

I did try to set a manual tab-order, this did not make any difference. (So I probably did it wrong)

Comment: If you have found the answer to this question, please add it as an answer (and only an answer) to this question. There is no need to edit your question to include the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the problem was that this was a 'pure' AS3 application wrapped in a Flex application - the UIComponent that was used as a wrapper needed the tabChildren property to be set, this way the available FocusManager would just work where before we needed to create a separate FocusManager just for the minigame. Making these changes made the problem go away.